# Is there a way to have alternating row colors in WinForm Table

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm new to all things .NET, and was tasked for some small changes.  I see there is a method to drawAllRows in the code I'm looking at.  If I do this, I can get the rows to alternate color:

```
           if (rowIndex % 2 == 0)
           {
               backColor = grayColor;
           }
           else
           {
               backColor = Color.White;
           }
```

This works on default.  However, because there is a sort capability, this won't always be correct as rows get resorted.  Is there a default way to do it in the properties?  Or some other method of achieveing this effect?  Thanks.

Comment: From your response to CodeCaster, I get the impression that this is a custom user control (I'm also not aware of drawAllRows as a standard method...but then there's plenty I'm unaware of)   If that's the case, and if the indexing of the rows is somehow different from the ordering of the rows after a sort.  Then I would think you'd need to dig into the Sorting methodology in order to figure out the actual ordering of the rows in the main control (e.g. while "rowIndex" may be a legitimate index for the items within a collection; it doesn't appear to be what dictates the display order).

Answer (score 7):

What kind of component are you using? A [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txth0a6h.aspx) has the `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` property which allows you to do exactly what you intend here.

Comment: It looks to be a subclass of System.Windows.Forms.UserControl